# Can't delete Kubernetes cluster with kops despite deleting everything at AWS

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, shutdown

For the last two hours, I have been unable to delete a cluster with kops even though I have deleted the only EC2 instance I had as well as my S3 bucket.

When I type:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

I get:

```
CURRENT   NAME                   CLUSTER                AUTHINFO               NAMESPACE
*         kubecourse.k8s.local   kubecourse.k8s.local   kubecourse.k8s.local
```

Next I type:

```
kops delete cluster --yes
```

But get:

```
Error: --name is required
Usage:
  kops delete cluster [CLUSTER] [flags]
```

Then I type:

```
kops delete cluster --name=kubecourse.k8s.local --yes
```

But get:

```
kops delete cluster --name=kubecourse.k8s.local
Error: State Store: Required value: Please set the --state flag or export KOPS_STATE_STORE.
For example, a valid value follows the format s3://<bucket>.
```

So I type:

```
 kops delete cluster --state=s3://k8-course-london
```

But this time get:

```
Error: --name is required
Usage:
  kops delete cluster [CLUSTER] [flags]
```

And I'm stuck in a cycle. Your help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like syntax used is wrong..

Right Syntax--
kops delete cluster --name=k8s.cluster.site --yes

https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cli/kops_delete_cluster/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Exact command:

kops delete cluster <cluster_name> --state <state_location> --yes